# How to find the i18n key from the value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I want to make a helper function which can take an English string as input and translate it to the desired language chosen by the user.

As all the locale files would be having key in common so I am looking for a way to find key using the string value. I am using default.yml files for storing translations.

After finding the key, I can use `<%= t() %>` for translating key to other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your yaml file looks like and it probably depends on what kind of I18n backend you use. If it's just key-value pairs for every language then something like this could work

```
I18n.backend.translations[:en].key "English string"
```

There is also the simple way. Just load the yaml file with the translations.

```
YAML.load_file("path_to_translations.yml").key "English string"
```

Comment: Thank you @periswon! I am using default SimpleBackend so reading translations from yml files only. The translations are present in nested hash-value - https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml#L94, so having difficulty in retrieving key from a particular value. I think I have to write the function for traversal myself. Or, is there any method?

Comment: I'm not aware of a method that does that. You can flatten the hash using this approach and then invert it: `flatten_hash(I18n.backend.translations[:en]).invert["Day"] # => :"datetime.prompts.day."`